# Using Bootstrap Datepicker, Javascript and Laravel query to go to a given link

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 3 tables : Each Event has Many Spots and Each Spot has Many Bookings.
So I am trying to get to the spots page where I have list of bookings shown using Bootstrap calendar picker.

I have a Bootstrap Calendar and 3 hidden input field(Vendor_id, Event_id and Date selected using changeDate event).

I am trying to pass those 3 inputs and get a spot_id(and finally go to the link).

Here's my code :

```
 <div class="calendar">
    <h2>Calendar</h2>
    <div id="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="today">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="my_hidden_input">
    <input type="hidden" id="event_id" value="{{ $event->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="vendor_id" value="{{ $event->vendor_id }}">
 </div>


//JavaScript
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#datepicker').datepicker();
   $('#datepicker').on("changeDate", function() {
   $('#my_hidden_input').val(
   $('#datepicker').datepicker('getFormattedDate')
   );
   var caldate = $('#my_hidden_input').val();
   var event_id = $('#event_id').val();
   var vendor_id = $('#vendor_id').val();
   //console.log(abc);
   //console.log(event_id);
   $.get("/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+caldate, function( data ) 
   {
        console.log(data);//I get this as UNDEFINED
        window.location.href="/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+data;
   });

   });
</script>

Controller Method
public function getspotid($vendor_id,$event_id,$date)
{

    $spotid = Spot::select('id')
    ->where('event_id','=',$event_id)
    ->where('event_date','=',$date)
    ->first();

    return response()->json(array('spotid' => $spotid));
}
```

I tested the controller and datepicker, everything seems to working, but I need a logic to return the value back to the Javascript and go to url : /{vendor_id}/events/{event_id}/{spot_id}. I

Comment: what is exactly the problem?are u not getting spotid in data of $.get?

Comment: Why not just have the Javascript handle the URL?

Comment: I am not getting the data in Javascript. I tried </br> $.each(data.spotid, function(index, value) 
     {
      console.log(value.id);
      
     });

Comment: I haven't really coded javascript before. Its something simple I am not able to resolve for past few hours. I also tried, window.location.href="/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+value.id;
But I get an error undefined as value.id. I am returning Json of format {"spotid":{"id":1}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

console.log( data );
instead of console.log(value.id);

Comment: I am getting an object finally. it has the id I need to pass it to url. At the moment. I ended up going to events/1/[object%20Object]. How do I get the object value in it?

Comment: window.location.href="/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+data.spotid;

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. I had to then simply get the value inside the object.
This is how I got it to work:
 $.get("/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+caldate, function( data ) 
    {

```
  console.log(data);
  window.location.href="/"+vendor_id+"/events/"+event_id +"/"+data.spotid.id;

});
```